Unable to correctly copy array
I wrote the following code to try and clone an array from an arraylist to another arraylist, but get the following output. Here is the code I wrote:
  await (()=>{
                        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        const cardID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
                        this.cards[i + 1] = this.deck[cardID];
                        this.positions[i] = {
                            x: start + this.offest,
                            y: 50,
                            card: this.deck[cardID]
                        }
                        delete this.deck[cardID];
                        start += this.offest;
                    }})();
                    
                    start = 350;
                    await (()=>{
                        for (let i = 6; i < 11; i++) {
                        const cardID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
                        this.cards.push(this.deck[cardID]);
                        this.positions[i] = {
                            x: start + this.offest,
                            y: 200,
                            card: this.deck[cardID],
                            
                        }
                        delete this.deck[cardID];
                        start += this.offest;
                    }})();
                    
                    
               
                   /** this.deck = this.deck.filter(function (el){
                        return el != null;
                    })
                **/
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                       
                       this.positions.map((v,i,a)=>{
                          
                            
                            let c = v["card"];
                            c["index"] = i
                            let animation = this.animator.Animation.new(c);
                            animation.moveTo(v.x,v.y,50,10);
                        
                            console.log(this.positions.length)
                        })
                        
                    },500)
                    this.hasAnimated = true;
                }else{
                    if(!this.inProgress && this.hasAnimated && Object.entries(this.animator.animations).length != 10 || Object.entries(this.animator.completed).length == 10){
                        if(this.deckIndex >= 1 && this.table.length > 1){
                            delete this.table[this.table.length - 1]
                        }
                        this.animator.clear();
                        console.log(this.table);
                        console.log(this.deck[this.deckIndex])
                        this.deck[this.deckIndex].hasShown = true;
                        this.table.push(this.deck[this.deckIndex]);
                        console.log(this.table);
                        
                        let animation = this.animator.Animation.new(this.deck[this.deckIndex]);
                        animation.moveTo(350,500,50,10);
                      
                        this.inProgress = true;

And it gives the following output:
[]
game.js:113 
[]
game.js:114 
Card {x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50, input: Input, …}
game.js:131 
[Card]
game.js:134 Uncaught (in promise) 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at game.js:134:47

I have tried using the Object.assign() function to assign a new value to the array, but go the same error. Also, when trying to use an iterator, it fails.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Have you tried the spread operator? Is the easiest way to clone an array/object. const originalArr = [1,2,3]; const cloneArr = [...originalArr]

@Frankusky yes i have, and it returns this error: TypeError: this.deck[this.deckIndex] is not iterable

you will need to share more code, if its possible, the full code, with the actual piece of code its impossible to know where is the issue

@Frankusky i have added as much code as i am willing to share

Kindly update your code. Please let me know if there are any issues.
if (this.deckIndex >= 1 && this.table.length > 1) {
    this.table.pop();
}
this.animator.clear();
console.log(this.table);
console.log(this.deck[this.deckIndex]);

if (this.deck[this.deckIndex]) { 
    this.deck[this.deckIndex].hasShown = true;
    this.table[this.deckIndex] = {...this.deck[this.deckIndex]}; 

    let animation = this.animator.Animation.new(this.deck[this.deckIndex]);
    animation.moveTo(350, 500, 50, 10);
    console.log(this.table);
    console.log(this.deck[this.deckIndex]);
    this.deck[this.deckIndex].hasShown = true;
} else {
    console.error('Deck index out of bounds:', this.deckIndex);
}


it would be helpful if you describe your fix along with the code you have provided.
